# Matrix representation of rotation proof?

Tags: matrices

C is for Cos, S is for sine
[image]

To find the matrix representation, we just apply R n to each of
the standard basis vectors, as in Equation 3.3, and then place the resulting vectors into the rows of a matrix (as in Equation 3.4). The
final result is:

How do I get this representation?

Comment: What axis is this rotation supposed to be about?

Comment: @Spencer $\langle x,y,z \rangle$, I would assume...

Answer (score 0):

The generators of rotations in three dimensions are,

$$
 \Sigma_x = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 
\end{array} \right)
\qquad
 \Sigma_y = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right)
\qquad 
 \Sigma_z = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right)
$$

To rotate about an axis $\vec{n} = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$ by an angle $\theta$ we apply the exponential map to $\theta \ \hat{n}\cdot \vec{\Sigma}$.

$$ R^\vec{n}(\theta) = \exp( \theta \  \hat{n} \cdot \Sigma )$$

Its possible to show that this results in,

$$ R^\vec{n}(\theta) = \mathbb{I} + (\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\Sigma} )^2 -(\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\Sigma} )^2 \cos(\theta) + (\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\Sigma})\sin(\theta),$$

this can be done using the fact that $(\hat{n}\cdot \Sigma)^3 = - \hat{n}\cdot\Sigma$ or by just working in the eigen basis of the matrix.

As an example consider $\vec{n} = \hat{z}$ then $\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\Sigma} = \Sigma_z$ and the expression reduces to,

$$ R^\hat{z}(\theta) = \mathbb{I} + (\Sigma_z )^2 -(\Sigma_z )^2 \cos(\theta) + (\Sigma_z)\sin(\theta)$$

$$  = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array} \right) + 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right) -
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right) \cos(\theta) + 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right)\sin(\theta)$$
$$=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\ \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array} \right)
$$

The expression for the general rotation can be obtained by placing the $\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\Sigma} = \frac{n_x}{\| \vec{n} \| } \Sigma_x + \frac{n_y}{\| \vec{n} \| } \Sigma_y + \frac{n_z}{\| \vec{n} \| } \Sigma_z $ into the equation and doing the matrix arithmetic involved.

Comment: This is the best I can do without some more information about the formalism that is being used in your course.